# Can I know if a video is H.264?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, video-encoding

I'm trying to find out whether a video uploaded through Carrierwave is encoded with H.264 or not. So far I tried the MiniExiftool gem since it lets me read a file's metadata. However I don't see it specified anywhere. Perhaps it's there and I'm just missing it. Any help, suggestions, or guidance? I'd appreciate it. Here's what I get when I use `MiniExiftool.new @file.path`.

```
=> #<MiniExiftool:0x007f7f82884628 @opts={:numerical=>false, :composite=>true, :
ignore_minor_errors=>false, :replace_invalid_chars=>false, :timestamps=>Time}, @
values={"exiftoolversion"=>8.9, "filesize"=>"35 MB", "filemodifydate"=>2014-04-2
8 18:46:51 +0000, "filepermissions"=>"rw-r--r--", "filetype"=>"MP4", "mimetype"=
>"video/mp4", "majorbrand"=>"MP4  Base Media v1 [IS0 14496-12:2003]", "minorvers
ion"=>"0.0.0", "compatiblebrands"=>["isom", "3gp4"], "movieheaderversion"=>0, "c
reatedate"=>2014-04-23 14:56:19 +0000, "modifydate"=>2014-04-23 14:56:19 +0000,
"timescale"=>1000, "duration"=>"14.28 s", "preferredrate"=>1, "preferredvolume"=
>"100.00%", "previewtime"=>"0 s", "previewduration"=>"0 s", "postertime"=>"0 s",
 "selectiontime"=>"0 s", "selectionduration"=>"0 s", "currenttime"=>"0 s", "next
trackid"=>3, "trackheaderversion"=>0, "trackcreatedate"=>2014-04-23 14:56:19 +00
00, "trackmodifydate"=>2014-04-23 14:56:19 +0000, "trackid"=>1, "trackduration"=
>"13.90 s", "tracklayer"=>0, "trackvolume"=>"0.00%", "imagewidth"=>1920, "imageh
eight"=>1080, "graphicsmode"=>"srcCopy", "opcolor"=>"0 0 0", "compressorid"=>"av
c1", "sourceimagewidth"=>1920, "sourceimageheight"=>1080, "xresolution"=>72, "yr
esolution"=>72, "bitdepth"=>24, "videoframerate"=>29.998, "matrixstructure"=>"1
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1", "mediaheaderversion"=>0, "mediacreatedate"=>2014-04-23 14:56:1
9 +0000, "mediamodifydate"=>2014-04-23 14:56:19 +0000, "mediatimescale"=>48000,
"mediaduration"=>"14.28 s", "handlertype"=>"Audio Track", "handlerdescription"=>
"SoundHandle", "balance"=>0, "audioformat"=>"mp4a", "audiochannels"=>2, "audiobi
tspersample"=>16, "audiosamplerate"=>48000, "moviedatasize"=>36819481, "avgbitra
te"=>"20.6 Mbps", "imagesize"=>"1920x1080", "rotation"=>0}, @changed_values={},
@errors={}, @filename="/home/user/uploads/dbrvp74x6r.mp4", @output="[{\n  \"SourceFile\": \"home/user/uploads/dbrvp74x6r.mp4\",\n  \"ExifToolVersion\": 8.90,\n  \"FileName\": \"dbrvp74x6r.mp4\",\n
 \"Directory\": \"home/user/uploads\",\n  \"FileSize\": \"35 MB\",\n  \"FileModifyDate\": \"2014:0
4:28 18:46:51+00:00\",\n  \"FilePermissions\": \"rw-r--r--\",\n  \"FileType\": \
"MP4\",\n  \"MIMEType\": \"video/mp4\",\n  \"MajorBrand\": \"MP4  Base Media v1
[IS0 14496-12:2003]\",\n  \"MinorVersion\": \"0.0.0\",\n  \"CompatibleBrands\":
[\"isom\",\"3gp4\"],\n  \"MovieHeaderVersion\": 0,\n  \"CreateDate\": \"2014:04:
23 14:56:19\",\n  \"ModifyDate\": \"2014:04:23 14:56:19\",\n  \"TimeScale\": 100
0,\n  \"Duration\": \"14.28 s\",\n  \"PreferredRate\": 1,\n  \"PreferredVolume\"
: \"100.00%\",\n  \"PreviewTime\": \"0 s\",\n  \"PreviewDuration\": \"0 s\",\n
\"PosterTime\": \"0 s\",\n  \"SelectionTime\": \"0 s\",\n  \"SelectionDuration\"
: \"0 s\",\n  \"CurrentTime\": \"0 s\",\n  \"NextTrackID\": 3,\n  \"TrackHeaderV
ersion\": 0,\n  \"TrackCreateDate\": \"2014:04:23 14:56:19\",\n  \"TrackModifyDa
te\": \"2014:04:23 14:56:19\",\n  \"TrackID\": 1,\n  \"TrackDuration\": \"13.90
s\",\n  \"TrackLayer\": 0,\n  \"TrackVolume\": \"0.00%\",\n  \"ImageWidth\": 192
0,\n  \"ImageHeight\": 1080,\n  \"GraphicsMode\": \"srcCopy\",\n  \"OpColor\": \
"0 0 0\",\n  \"CompressorID\": \"avc1\",\n  \"SourceImageWidth\": 1920,\n  \"Sou
rceImageHeight\": 1080,\n  \"XResolution\": 72,\n  \"YResolution\": 72,\n  \"Bit
Depth\": 24,\n  \"VideoFrameRate\": 29.998,\n  \"MatrixStructure\": \"1 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 1\",\n  \"MediaHeaderVersion\": 0,\n  \"MediaCreateDate\": \"2014:04:23 14
:56:19\",\n  \"MediaModifyDate\": \"2014:04:23 14:56:19\",\n  \"MediaTimeScale\"
: 48000,\n  \"MediaDuration\": \"14.28 s\",\n  \"HandlerType\": \"Audio Track\",
\n  \"HandlerDescription\": \"SoundHandle\",\n  \"Balance\": 0,\n  \"AudioFormat
\": \"mp4a\",\n  \"AudioChannels\": 2,\n  \"AudioBitsPerSample\": 16,\n  \"Audio
SampleRate\": 48000,\n  \"MovieDataSize\": 36819481,\n  \"AvgBitrate\": \"20.6 M
bps\",\n  \"ImageSize\": \"1920x1080\",\n  \"Rotation\": 0\n}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this video is h.264. `"CompressorID": "avc1"`. AVC = Advanced Video Coding = h.264

Comment: So all I need to look at is the CompressorID?

Comment: I do not know. I do not code in rub, and I have never used MiniExiftool. For THIS video, the codec value is displayed as the CompressorID value. But it may be different for other containers.